# BASED ON NEWTON'S 3RD LAW

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

my question is based on newton's 3rd law . An elephant pushes a rabbit with $250 N$ force , then the rabbit should also apply $250 N$ force but the rabbit is only capable  to apply $25 N$ force . **Why does this happen?** . According to Newton's 3rd law the rabbit should also apply this much of force .